# Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle'

Tags: c#, xna

I create a dictionary with 3 floats and 3 Rectangles. After that, I create a list to sort the dictionary. The lowest float should be the first entry in the list. Finally, I want that the variable `FirstRectInList` has the same values as the Rectangle of the first entry in the list.
But I always get this error message:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle'*

What is wrong?
The variable `FirstRectInList` should get the value of the dictionary: `(0, 0, random.Next(101), random.Next(101))`. And not the key of the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<float, Rectangle> Users = new Dictionary<float, Rectangle>();

for (int j = 0; j <= 3 - 1; j++)
{
  float Points = random.Next(101);
  Users.Add(Points, new Rectangle(0, 0, random.Next(101), random.Next(101)));
}
var list = Users.Keys.ToList();
list.Sort();

Rectangle FirstRectInList = list[0];
```

Comment: It needs to be: FirstRectInList = Users[list[0]].  Do note that the odds that the code will crash are non-zero, you are not doing anything to ensure that the key is unique.  The code doesn't make much sense so an alternative is hard to suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` contains only the keys of type `float` of the `Users` dictionary. It doesn't contain the values of type `Rectangle`.
Therefore, `list[0]` returns the smallest key and not the `Rectangle` of the smallest key.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you can use LINQ:

```
Rectangle FirstRectInList = Users.OrderBy(x => x.Key).First().Value;
```